# Commutation Relationship

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, commutator

For the Hamiltonian of the hydrogen atom, does the square of angular momentum, 
$$L^2 = L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$$
commute with Hamiltonian operator, 
$$H = \frac{1}{2m}(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2) + V(r)~?$$
Should the $1/r$ of $V(r)$, potential energy, also be changed to Cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum is defined as,
$$
L=r\times p\equiv r\times\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla
$$
From this it follows that
$$
\left[L_x,\,x\right]=\left[L_x,\,p_x\right]=0
$$
where
$$
L_x\sim yp_z-zp_y
$$
Noting that
$$
\left[A,BC\right]=\left[A,B\right]C+B\left[A,C\right]
$$
the expected results can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

Any, the Hamiltonian whos potential nergy is a function of $r$ only  has rotational invariance.  Since the components of $\mathbf{L}$ are generators of rotation, it can be shown that $[\mathbf{L},V]=[L^2,V]=0$

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for the hydrogen atom Hamiltonian, $L^2$ commutes with the Hamiltonian because it commutes with $r^2$.

Comment: Does not $L^2$ commute with $p^2$? Which co-ordinate system do I use?

Comment: @Sunee: In order to ask common homework style questions like this, it is preferred to first show your own attempt. If you would add this to the original post I'm sure someone will help you find your error.